# Could this resistor be intended to do anything other than inrush limit?

Tags: rectifier

Repaired a little board today that had a simple half wave rectifier on it. The capacitor had a resistor (R1) in series, that was obviously getting hot and wasting a lot of power. I assume the resistor is just to limit inrush, but it seems really inefficient. The board generates a DCish voltage from stepped down AC (12V) for driving a magnetic lock coil.

Schematic:
[image: Half Wave Rectifier Circuit]

A quick analysis shows that if the load is reasonably constant current, and the capacitor voltage is fairly constant, then the average ripple current through the capacitor branch is the same as the load current. That means unless your load is equivalent to significantly higher than a 100 Ohm resistance, you're wasting half your power or more in that extra resistor.

Am I missing another purpose for that resistor? I've simulated the circuit waveforms, and can't see any desirable difference when the resistor is added.

Edit:
The final conclusion on my end was that the resistor is a necessary evil to damp the ring-down of the parallel L and C when the power is shut off. If the electromagnet coil is allowed to ring, it can manifest as a residual force for a perceptible amount of time, making the door annoying to open immediately after the lock is disengaged.

Comment: I have mainly seem this arrangement in damped input filters for SMPS. But it is always accompagnied by bulk capacitance which limits the voltage ripple and hence limits the current going through R1.
Without the bulk it is pretty inefficient yes.

Comment: It's not an inrush limiter, rather inductive kickback limiter, also the MOV serves the same purpose.

Comment: Also arguably a "spreading resistor" that increases the conduction angle over which the AC cycles provide capacitor charging current. It would be strangish to use a value that got overly hot. A full wave bridge rectifier at the input will greatly improve the ripple current and reduce the resistor dissipation.

Comment: Late to the party, but can you please confirm the capacitor isn't 220 *n*F?

Comment: @greybeard I can confirm based on photos of this device that the capacitor value was definitely 220 **micro**farad.